# Divisible Pairs in a range

Tags: c, algorithm, number-theory

I need help figuring out a better approach to this problem (a more mathematical one maybe!). Here are the details:

Problem statement:

*Given N and M you need to find out how many pairs a,b (1 <= a < b <=N) are there such that (a+b) is divisible by M. For example when N=4 and M=3, there are 2 possible pairs the sum of which is divisible by M and they are (1,2) and (2,4).*

*Constraints: 1 <= N <= 10^9 and 2 <= M <= 10^9.*
Time constraint: 1 second

In my algorithm, I've looped N times, making it an O(N) algo. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef unsigned long long ULL;
int main()
{
    int t,m,n,a; ULL ans=0;
    scanf("%d\n",&t);
    while(t--) // test cases
    {
            // Main logic
        scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);
        ans=0;
        for(a=1;a<n;a++)
            ans += (n+a)/m - (a*2)/m;
        printf("%llu\n",ans);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm simply checking how many numbers are divisible by M in the range (2a,n+a) where 1 =< a < n. If you look at the sum of all *(a,b)* in the range, you will know why I've taken *(2a,n+a)*.

However this *O(N)* approach isn't very fast. For N=10<sup>9</sup> and M=2, the program prints the answer as 249999999500000000 in 12 seconds, which is pretty slow. What other approaches can be used? I can't think of any better approach. Please help!

Comment: Instead of testing, generate them: (M, 0), (M-1, 1), (M-2, 2), etc., then (2M, 0), (2M-1, 1), etc.

Comment: You mean going the opposite way? Means finding out in how many ways can I split the multiples of M in 2 +ve integers which fall in the range [1,N] ? That's even more difficult and time taking

Comment: @Rushil It's more difficult, but way faster, see philips answer

Answer (score 3):

Instead of testing, you can simply count.

Let's list all possible pairs:

```
(1, N - (N+1)%M),
(1, N - M - (N+1)%M),
(1, N - 2*M - (N+1)%M),
...
(2, N - (N+1)%M - 1),
(2, N - M - (N+1)%M - 1),
(2, N - 2*M - (N+1)%M - 1),
...
```

(We need to subtract `(N+1)%M` from the second element of the tuple in order to make the element sum divisible by M)

More generally, given `N` and `M` > 0, every pair `(a, b)` with `1 <= a < b <= N` such that `a+b % M == 0` must have the following form:

`(i+1, N - d*M - (N+1)%M - i)` for `0 <= d` and `0 <= i`

Now you have to answer the following two questions:

- What is the maximum value for `i`?
- Given `i`, what is the maximum value for `d`, i.e. for each valid `i`, how many pairs `(i+1, ...)` do exist?

Once you found out, you should be able to come up with a formula to determine the number of valid pairs in constant time.

Comment: did you mean `N+1%M` or `(N+1)%M` ? Coz `1%M` is always 1.

Comment: well I'll have to run a loop I guess. But it surely be faster than my previous program..In the worst case, the loop will run N/2 times.

Answer (score 0):

```
ans = n / m * (n - 1)
    + (n / m) * (n / m - 1) / 2 * m
    + (n % m + m / 2) / m * (n - m + n % m)
    + (n - m + n % m) % m * (n / m)
    - (n / m) * (n / m - 1) * m
    - (m / 2) * (n / m)
    - (n % m) * (n / m * 2)
    - (n % m / ((m + 1) / 2)) * (n % m % ((m + 1) / 2));
```

Comment: Flash back to Fortran77 nearly complete.